# Do something on every second page

Tags: page-numbering, document-configuration

Does there exist a way to only print the main text in the document on every *second* page while running some other code on the other pages? What I want is something that runs like in the below example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{atevenpages}
  The content of this environment is supposed to be printed on even-numbered pages. On the other hand, even-numbered pages are supposed to contain none of the main text.
\end{atevenpages}

This is the main text, which is only to appear on odd-numbered pages.
\lipsum[1-22]
\end{document}
```

Comment: [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135688/579) asks for much the same result; unfortunately, it doesn't have an answer.  an approach to parallel texts across a two-page spread is given in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165019/579).

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/if-then-else-for-odd-page-even-page, I guess it answers your question

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen, I may very well be wrong, but I don't see any obvious way to apply that to this problem. I need the same code to be executed at *every even page*, not just once *if* the page is even.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, there may very well be a solution there, but I'm afraid I don't understand much of the code in your second link. :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the `everypage` and `ifthen` package. `everypage` introduces a hook which is called after each page has been set. So I need to call my `\checkthatpage` command only for the first page manually, for all other pages the hook is used. There may be more sophisticated solutions, but I haven't found them, yet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,everypage}

\newcommand{\checkthatpage}[2]{%
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
    {#1}%
    {#2}%
}%

\AddEverypageHook{\checkthatpage{Even}{Odd}}

\begin{document}

Foo

\clearpage

Bar

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds very promising indeed! I'll try it out and return shortly. :-)

Comment: For some reason, it stops working after the second page. Try adding some more `\clearpage`s and notice the result. "Even" and "Odd" are completely missing.

Comment: Strange, I'll have a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: I looked at the documentation for `afterpage`. It seems it is only for running code after the *current* page, not after *all* pages.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `everypage`?

Comment: I think you did. Replace `\afterpage` with `\AddEverypageHook`, then it works. I shall accept your answer after this has been corrected.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had been lookign for. I have adjusted the code.

Comment: I would use `\value{page}` instead of `\thepage`, as the latter may return roman numbers or other kinds of fancy formatting. See [what-is-the-proper-method-of-accessing-a-counter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/what-is-the-proper-method-of-accessing-a-counter)

Comment: I have changed that in the code, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 7):

I would tackle this problem at a lower level: The `\shipout` routine, which is invoked by TeX when a page is full and needs to be shipped out. At this stage, we can just add another page with the intended content:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \EvenPageContent%
    \newpage
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\EvenPageContent}{%
  The content of this environment is supposed to be printed on even-numbered pages. On the other hand, even-numbered pages are supposed to contain none of the main text.
}

\begin{document}

This is the main text, which is only to appear on odd-numbered pages.
\lipsum[1-22]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, thinking a bit more about it, that is basically the same approach as suggested by Uwe. It is just based on other packages.

Comment: Yes, for most purposes, it works exactly the same way. But actually, this approach made some things work better in my concrete document. :-)

Comment: So thanks for the answer, it may be the one I end up using. :-)

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of the code `\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout \box\AtBeginShipoutBox`. It rendered a warning in my document, and when I commented it out, everything still worked. I looked into the documentation of `atbegshi`, but did not get many answers there. What does that code do?

Comment: @Gaussler: You are absolutely right, it is not necessary! The purpose was to ship out the current page (provided in `\AtBeginShipoutBox`) _before_ inserting the `\EvenPageContent`, so that the latter does not make it accidentally onto an odd page. However, that was a logical mistake: When the shipout handler is invoked, LaTeX has already finished the construction of the odd page, so new content goes to the next page anyway. I have simplified the code.