# How to execute a command after every automatic break?

Tags: macros

I want to trigger a macro after automatic page break. I have tried the everypage package, but the `\AddEverypageHook{}` seems to only work on background layer. What I want is for the macro to execute in the main text.

Comment: Something like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166155 ?

Comment: Load `atbegshi` and then
`\AtBeginShipout{This is written on every new page}`.

Comment: note that all macros are expanded and all line breaking completed well before page breaks are considered so you can not insert text in the main text run, affecting the main paragraph text,  at a page break.

Comment: @CarLaTeX It works a treat! Thanks!

Comment: Yes @Schrödinger'scat exactly like that.